# Count lines in a table?

Tags: algorithm

I have a long table of numbers. In each line I have 15 numbers all in the range from 1 to 25.

Given that a number N among the 25 numbers appeared in a line I'd like to count how many times the same N appeared in the line just below.

For example,

```
2 3 4 12 14....

2 5 7 9 10...

1 3 4 20 21...

2 4 5 6 10...

2 12 7 8 10..

2 11 19 25 14..
```

If these were all the lines I have, the algorithm should return for N=2 the value 3 because 2 was followed by itself thrice. For N=4 the algorithm should return the value 2.

Does anyone know an easy way to do it?

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far? Do you have any code examples of what you were doing?

Comment: Can you clarify something? *I'd like to count how many times the same N appeared in the line just below* - if N=2, then 2 only appears once in the line below?

Comment: @notyou You count every time a line satisfies the criterium. For example, for N=2 the lines 1, 4, 5 satisfy this..

Comment: @pnuts because it occurs in two consecutive rows (row 3 and 4)

Comment: @notyou He tries to develop somewhat of a streak counter.. So the consecutive rows are important...

Comment: @creyD Indeed I'm a mathematician, I'm not very skilled in programming, although I can code some C..

Comment: So the question should be *"For input N, how many consecutive lines contain N, not including the input line"* or something like that?

Comment: Indeed, I found it difficult to describe by words..

Answer (score 2):

The pseudo is simple. Search each row `arr[i][:]` (i-th row), if found `N` in row `i` and row `i+1`, count `+1`.

Comment: I believe we'll have to modify a bit because the 2 may occupy different columns along the lines.

Comment: Maybe we could create a matrix with 25 entries and every time a number does not appear in the line we put 0 there..

Comment: @PtF: it is modified.

Comment: @pnuts: it is modified.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you probably need a counter-variable for each number (you may initiate them when the numbers occur first).

There are two simple ways for doing this:

1. Check every row if it contains the number if yes and then counter++, if not then counter = 0.
2. For each number of the first day look at the next day if it occurs, if yes then increase counter if not then stop counter.

I could write a function in Lua (or similar) real quick if it would help you.

**Edit:** Somewhat overcomplicated (...) this function (way 1):

```
testdata = {{2, 3, 4, 12, 14},{2, 5, 7, 9, 10},{1, 3, 4, 20, 21},{2, 4, 5, 6, 10},{2, 12, 7, 8, 10},{2, 11, 19, 25, 14}}

-- Thanks @wookai for this function draft
function table.contains(table, testedNumber)
    for j=1, #table do
        if table[j] == testedNumber then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

function getStreakForNumber(number)
    max = 0 counter = 0
    for i=1, #testdata do   -- Iterate over the provided data, check if the table contains the number and increase the counter
        if table.contains(testdata[i], number) then
            counter = counter + 1
        else
            if counter > max then
                max = counter
            end
            counter = 0
        end
    end
    if counter > max then
        max = counter
    end
    return max
end

print(getStreakForNumber(4)) -- prints 2
print(getStreakForNumber(2)) -- prints 3
```

Comment: @PtF As promised the lua draft. Hope this helps you.

Comment: It "prints 2" as the result of the highest streak achieved by the line 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quickly thrown together Java example - most likely not efficient etc but I haven't a great deal of time this morning:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\your\\filepath\\filename.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int count = 0;
    int tempcount = 0;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String[] space = list.get(i).split("\\s+");
        if (Arrays.asList(space).contains("2")) { //this is your number
            tempcount++;
        } else {
            tempcount = 0;
        }
        if (tempcount > count) {
            count = tempcount;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```